Как убрать в рассылке от плагина Contact Form 7 уведомление о спаме?
Установил плагин Contact Form 7 на WordPress, настроил всё по документации, но в рассылке(автоматический ответ) клиенту и уведомлении на почту, есть такое уведомление: "Изображения в этом сообщении скрыты. Сообщение похоже на мошенническое или спам." . Дополнительно еще поставил плагин WP Mail SMTP , настраивал через сервер Brevo, так как с обычного сервера, где сайт, вообще письма не доставлялись. В Brevo так же всё настроил и прошел валидацию. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и как убрать уведомление о спаме??
P.S. письма в Спам не попадают, только уведомление о Спаме

